# I'm tried installing aws command line tool

Tags: aws-cli

I tried installing the aws command line tool to run the command

```
aws
```

on linux

i tried installing it using pip but I get an error
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-other-os

```
/bin/aws: Permission denied
```

whenever I run the command

```
aws help
```

what should I do?

Comment: doesn't work. also i'm already running it as root

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /bin/aws`?

Comment: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 814 Oct 22 18:09 /bin/aws

Comment: try again after running `chmod 755 /bin/aws`

Comment: btw do you know what a NAT IP is?

Comment: @Wimmel you should add the chmod as an answer. This worked for me as well.

Comment: @Dez I normally don't add such simple one-liner answers, assuming it won't help anybody else. But as you were able to find this question too, I have added it with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The output of `ls -l /bin/aws` shows:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 814 Oct 22 18:09 /bin/aws
```

Which means you have read/write permissions, but no execute permissions. To fix that, you have to run [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) like this:

```
chmod 755 /bin/aws
```

After this the output of `ls -l /bin/aws` should show:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 814 Oct 22 18:09 /bin/aws
```

The `x` means you also have execute permissions now. Also other users will have execute permission. If there are no other limitations, other users can execute it too.

Comment: Thanks @Wimmel for the answer. For all the non-Windows options on [this install page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) I had to run `chmod 755` on the file to make it executable.

Comment: I had the same issue, except my `aws` directory had `777` permissions. Changing those to `755` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and couldn't get it to work.
I uninstalled it using the [directions on the aws site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-remove)

I then installed it using homebrew on linux instead, and it works fine:

```
# as of writing installs aws-cli v2.X
brew install awscli
```